# Adonis.js validate request.multipart.file image size & extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, multipart, adonis.js

I am trying to validate size and extension from images present in the request as multipart/form-data.

What i tried but didnt worked:

```
const validationOptions = {
    types: ['image'],
    size: '2mb',
    extnames: ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg']
}

await request.multipart.file('front_img', validationOptions, async (file) => {
    const file_content = await getStream.buffer(file.stream);
    request.front_img_b64 = Buffer.from(file_content).toString('base64');
});
```

request.multipart.file seems to have a "options" array where i passed the validationsOptions object but does not have any effect.

How i can validate images size and extension in my middleware ?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how Validate Multipart File - AdonisJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57193772/how-validate-multipart-file-adonisjs)